# How to insert a box in equations to indicate spaces for writing answers in an exam paper?

Tags: equations

Currently, I use write things like

```
\[
3 + 4 = \underline{\hspace{2cm}}
\]
```

in the exam paper I am preparing. The `\underline` indicates where students should write their answer.

However, I want to change the underlines into empty boxes where students can fill in answers, such as a number. This allows me to control how large font they write.

Comment: Please elaborate about what output you exactly need. And not related but you should not use `$$ ... $$` in LaTeX, but `\[ ... \]` instead or just `$ ... $` if it's inline math. [See this very extensive post about that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\parindent=0mm
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item   3+4=\\ \hfill \framebox(\textwidth,10){}\\
        \item 7x5=\\ \hfill \framebox(\textwidth,10){}\\
        \item $\dfrac{x^2-1}{x-1}=$\\ \hfill \framebox(\textwidth,20){}\\
        \item $ \int x^2\,dx=$\\ \hfill \framebox(\textwidth,30){}\\
        \item Make the construction of an equilater triangle with a ruler and a compass.\\ \hfill \framebox(\textwidth,150){}\\
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and his output:

[image]